# Why do inactive SSH sessions terminate with "Write Failed: Broken pipe"?

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp

I know that this is a common problem with a known solution. A quick web search turns up many results that point you toward the `ServerAliveInterval` (or less commonly the server-side `ClientAliveInterval`) configuration options. Setting one of these to some arbitrary value such as 15, 60, or 120 will solve the broken pipe issue.

My question is *why*? Why does this happen in the first place? Who is closing the socket?

I have my doubts about the OS killing the connection due to inactivity, given the fact that the `TCPKeepAlive` option is enabled by default, which causes TCP keepalive messages to be sent in order to detect clients dropping offline. So the OS won't see the connection as inactive anyway.

In that case, is it the `sshd` itself that is timing them out? And if so, why isn't that timeout documented or configurable? And if application-level keepalives are needed to keep SSH connections open, then why are they not enabled by default?

These questions are invariably overlooked whenever this issue pops up on discussion forums. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

SSH itself is quite an old protocol, and wasn't originally designed for the mobile oriented world we live in today. If there's an interruption in the connection between server and client it doesn't recover very well, so if you're on an iffy connection, it wouldn't be too much of a surprise if there was a broken pipe. This is also partially due to the fact that SSH is completely reliant on TCP, which has a number of limitations in this area.

Either way, if you need something that is more robust for such connections, I recommend mosh. It's super easy to configure, and you shouldn't have any issue with disconnecting. In fact, you could even switch IP addresses and it will pick right back up where you were without so much as a hiccup. Mosh uses UDP, which is what allows for such behavior.

As for how it works, it uses SSH to establish a connection to the server, where it runs `mosh-server`. The program then listens on a UDP port (around 60000 by default), for the client to connect with `mosh-client`. This means that the only configuration you have to do is a simple port forward.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not the problem. I've had this happen on many rock-solid connections. It does not happen, however, if data is being sent periodically. I have an SSH tunnel that I use for an application. If the application is open the connection will stay up forever (days, weeks). If I close the application, I will soon see a broken pipe.

Comment: @Frogging101 Can you please describe exactly how you do this? Also, what reason do you have for leaving an ssh connection open for weeks?

Comment: I run `ssh -L 58846:localhost:58846 [server]`, and then I open Deluge (a torrent client) running, and connect it to localhost:58846. The details aren't really important, the point is that when the program is open (and therefore sending data periodically), the connection stays open.

I manage servers, and it's a minor annoyance when every day I have to restart my shell sessions because they've dropped overnight due to inactivity. And as I said, I do know how to solve the problem. But being a programmer myself, I am quite curious as to what is responsible for the inactivity timeout.

Answer (score 1):

> Who is closing the socket?

Nobody is closing the "socket", i.e. neither client nor server. The connection problem is usually caused by a stateful packet filteri in between the communication parties. Such packet filters are used in firewalls and also in the simple SoHo routers where they are needed to handle the states for [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) which is the typical way to provide internet access to multiple internal systems behind the same external IP address.

Such stateful packet filters create a state for each new connection and tears it down on connection close. This means SYN/FIN packets with TCP connections like ssh. These states takes up memory so a packet filter can only support a limited number of states at the same time. Therefore it will remove these states after some time of inactivity (i.e. no packets for this connection).

If there is no activity within a TCP connection no packets will be send. This is true for SSH too. After some time of inactivity the state in the packet filter will be removed. If any party of the connection then will send more packets after the inactivity there will be no state in the packet filter and a RST packet will be issued. This results in the "Broken Pipe".

The TCPKeepAlive option in SSH enables the TCP keepalive option which causes the TCP layer to regularly send empty packets (i.e. TCP packet with no data payload) in times of inactivity. This way the packet filter keeps the state open.

Comment: The `TCPKeepAlive` option is enabled by default, and the broken pipe still occurs. The `ServerAliveInterval` option solves it, and I am wondering why, given that there are already TCP keepalive packets being sent (which will already pacify any stateful packet filter that would cause this problem).

Comment: @Frogging101: TCP keep alive can have really long pauses between the keep alive packets (2 hours on many Linux systems). The packet filter might have lower timeouts in which case TCP keep alive does not help much. ServerAliveInterval instead is a feature similar to TCP keep alive but at the application level and if one uses short times it will keep the state open.